# Alternatives for creating graphs in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, graph, if-statement

I recently created a program that calculates flow rate through a pipe and generates, line by line, a scatter graph of the output. My knowledge of C is rudimentary (started with python) and I get the feeling that I may have made the code overly complicated. As such, I am asking if anyone has any alternatives to the code below. Critiques of code structure etc. are also welcome!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI 3.1415926

double 
flow_rate(double diameter, double k, double slope){
    double area, w_perimeter, hyd_rad, fr;

    area = (PI*pow(diameter,2.0))/8.0;
    w_perimeter = (PI*diameter)/2.0;
    hyd_rad = area/w_perimeter;

    fr = (1.0/k)*area*pow(hyd_rad,(2.0/3.0))*pow(slope,(1.0/2.0));

return fr;
}

int 
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double avg_k=0.0312, min_slope=0.0008;
    float s3_diameter; 
    int i=0, num=0, flow_array[6] ,rows, align=29;
    char graph[] = "                             ";
    char graph_temp[]= "                             ";

    printf("\nFlow Rate (x 10^-3) m^3/s\n");

    for (s3_diameter=0.50;s3_diameter>0.24;s3_diameter-=0.05){
        flow_array[i] = (1000*(flow_rate(s3_diameter, avg_k, min_slope))+0.5);
        i += 1;
    }

    for (rows=30;rows>0;rows--){
        strcpy(graph_temp,graph);
        for (num=0;num<6;num++){
            if (rows==flow_array[num] && rows%5==0){
                graph_temp[align] = '*';
                printf("%d%s\n",rows,graph_temp);
                align -= 5;
                break;
            }
            else if (rows==flow_array[num]){
                graph_temp[align] = '*';
                printf("|%s\n",graph_temp);
                align -= 5;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (rows%5==0 && num==5){
                    printf("%d%s\n",rows,graph_temp);
                } 
                else if (rows%5!=0 && num==5){
                    printf("|%s\n",graph_temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("|----2----3----3----4----4----5----\n");
    printf("     5    0    5    0    5    0\n");
    printf("       Diameter (x 10^-2) m\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output as below.

```
Flow Rate (x 10^-3) m^3/s
30                             
|                             
|                             
|                             
|                             
25                             
|                             
|                             
|                             *                             
|                             
20                             
|                             
|                             
|                        *    
|                             
15                             
|                             
|                             
|                   *         
|                             
10                             
|              *              
|                             
|                             
|         *                   
5                             
|    *                        
|                             
|                             
|                             
|----2----3----3----4----4----5----
     5    0    5    0    5    0
       Diameter (x 10^-2) m
```

Comment: Do you *want* your graphs to be ASCII-art-like or was this just the way you started out? Did you consider using something like gnuplot, for example?

Comment: For the fixed constraints of the equation, the code isn't too bad.  You could use `sqrt(slope)` in place of `pow(slope, (1.0/2.0))`.  You could use `int main(void)` since you ignore the command-line arguments. You might want to think about how to generalize the processing; ranges, labels, scaling, width, height, where the numbers go, etc.  You might decide to have the user specify the data to be plotted as lines from a file, or you might provide a way to use different functions compiled into the program for different formulae.

Comment: Your function definitions look funny - is the return-type-in-an-extra-line thing some sort of convention that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @l4mpi it's part of the GNU coding standards

Answer (score 0):

GNUPlot is by far the simplest way to draw graph in C.
It can draw from simple plotting to complex 3d graph, and even provides an ASCII Art output (if ASCII output is really required)

You can find more information on how to use GNUPlot in a C program here: http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/